# using empty does not provide correct results

Tags: php

Can someone please tell me why I'm able to echo inside of this block when the session clearly has a value?

```
$_SESSION['test']['testing'] = 'hgkjhg';
echo $_SESSION['test']['testing']; // Produces hgkjhg (Clearly not empty)

if(empty($_SESSION['test']['testing'])){
echo 'Hello'; // This echoes and to me, shouldn't
}
```

Comment: Sorry Didn't get your question....?

Comment: Read it carefully  :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I'm reading it but don't see anything that would indicate why my example should work. In my case, 'testing' has 'hgkjhg' as it's value so it is set which means it is NOT empty yet I can echo hello

Comment: Try: `var testvar = $_SESSION['test']['testing'];` and see if testvar is empty.

Comment: Is this verbatim the exact same code that you're having problems with?

Comment: For the record, I plugged the OP's code into my local machine and it works the way it should; it's not echoing 'Hello'.

Comment: Are you using start_session() inbetween or something or in any other way pummeling your $_SESSION variable?

Comment: I did that and a var_dump shows it being a string. It

Comment: @deceze, yes... I copied it and pasted it.

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo, I can't imagine why it isn't working correctly here.

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference, but it might: try assigning `$_SESSION['test']['testing']` to a variable and then putting that variable into the `empty()` method instead and see if that does anything. Could be an old funky PHP thing...?

Comment: @jim: Also try changing your IF statement to `if(empty($_SESSION['test']['testing']) === TRUE)` to see if that has any affect.

Comment: @roe: It should be session_start(), I suppose

Comment: Are you using a custom session handler?

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using? If not, please show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is about [session_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Unlike [session_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php), assigning directly to $_SESSION does not automatically call session_start.

Directly from PHP manual for session_register()

> If session_start() was not called
>   before this function is called, an
>   implicit call to session_start() with
>   no parameters will be made. $_SESSION
>   does not mimic this behavior and
>   requires session_start()

Comment: This would mean that OP is not actually getting a result from the second line of his code, as he says he is. Is this correct? `echo $_SESSION['test']['testing']; // Produces hgkjhg (Clearly not empty)
`

Comment: might just be stored in a local/global $_SESSION variable, not the one stored in server.

Comment: by the way, I tried it on my PC, $_SESSION will really output after it has been assigned, but will not be stored on server and re-fetched on another page unless you use session_start();

Comment: Most likely OP is not sharing important details. It definitely doesn't make sense to me in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the rest of your code. Something is either hanging in the session, or you're assigning values elsewhere in your script.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['test']['testing'] = 'hgkjhg';
echo $_SESSION['test']['testing']; // Produces hgkjhg (Clearly not empty)

if(empty($_SESSION['test']['testing'])){
echo 'Hello'; // This echoes and to me, shouldn't
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Results:

hgkjhgarray(1) { ["test"]=> array(1) { ["testing"]=> string(6) "hgkjhg" } }

Just for argument's sake, you are saying you see "Hello" rather than "hgkjhg". "hgkjhg" should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it into:

```
$_SESSION['test']['testing'] = 'hgkjhg';
echo $_SESSION['test']['testing']; 

if(empty($_SESSION['test']['testing'])){
    echo 'Hello. Error in $_SESSION !'; 
}
```

If it is still echoing "Hello", then you have somewhere later in your code a line with:

```
echo 'Hello';
```